# Operator norm and spectrum

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, sp.spectral-theory, operator-norms

I am wondering about when an operator norm coincides with the maximum eigenvalue of an operator and there is one particular aspect that confuses me quite a lot.

Let's say we have a symmetric positive continuous linear operator
$$
T : L^2(\Omega) \rightarrow L^2(\Omega)
$$
with maximum eigenvalue $\lambda>0$ so that $T u = \lambda u$ for some eigenfunction $u\in L^2(\Omega)$. Then (if I understand it correctly), it should hold
$$
\lambda = \sup_{v \in L^2(\Omega)  \setminus \{ 0 \}} \frac{\| Tv \|_{L^2(\Omega)}}{\| v \|_{L^2(\Omega)}}.
$$
Next, let's assume that the operator has a smoothing effect such that $\mbox{image}(T) \subset H^1_0(\Omega)$ and that it is also $H^1$-continuous (I am thinking of $T$ as the inverse of an elliptic differential operator). In this case we can interpret the operator as
$$
T : H^1_0(\Omega) \rightarrow H^1_0(\Omega)
$$
The spectrum should remain unchanged, so that I would think that
$$
\lambda = \sup_{v \in H^1_0(\Omega) \setminus \{ 0 \}} \frac{\| Tv \|_{H^1_0(\Omega)}}{\| v \|_{H^1_0(\Omega)}}.
$$
However, the statement
$$
\sup_{v \in H^1_0(\Omega)} \frac{\| Tv \|_{H^1_0(\Omega)}}{\| v \|_{H^1_0(\Omega)}} = \lambda = \sup_{v \in L^2(\Omega)} \frac{\| Tv \|_{L^2(\Omega)}}{\| v \|_{L^2(\Omega)}}.
$$
looks wrong to me. Is it? If so, where is the mistake in my arguments? I feel like I have a very basic misunderstanding here.

Comment: If the operator is not self-adjoint/symmetric, then the formula is for singular value, not eigenvalue.

Comment: Thanks! I missed the point with the singular values. Let's say the operator is also symmetric, is the statement true then?

Comment: A brief remark (though not essential for the question): your assumption that $T$ be continuous from $L^2$ to $H^1_0$ is redundant; this follows automatically from the closed graph theorem.

Comment: If we have the identity $Tu = \lambda u$ for $u\not = 0$ (strongly in $H^1(\Omega)$), then $(T - \lambda I) u = 0$, which means that $(T - \lambda I)$ cannot be invertible. This should not change depending on if we interpret $T$ as an operator on $L^2(\Omega)$ or on $H^1_0(\Omega)$. What do I miss here?

Comment: Good point, i take that back.

Comment: I don't think there's anything very mysterious about this. Under the stated assumptions, we secretly know that $\|Tv\|/\|v\|$ (with both norms) is maximized by the maximum eigenvector, and then of course it doesn't matter which norm we use.

Comment: @ChristianRemling I think the concern by OP here is that one supremum is taken over a smaller space (in the sense that one embeds continuously (even compactly - Rellich Kondrachov!)) into the other, but the suprema are the same, when it seems like the supremum over the smaller space should be smaller (possibly strictly) than that taken over the largest space.

Comment: Do we know that $T$ is self-adjoint as an operator on $H_0^1(\Omega)$?

Comment: @MateuszKwaśnicki: No, the operator need not be self-adjoint on $H_0^1$, and this is apparently the main problem here..

Comment: @ChristianRemling: In fact, the quotient of the $H^1_0$-norms need not be maximized by the leading eigenvector (as follows, for instance, from my answer below).

Answer (score 7):

The major point here is that, for an operator $S$ on a Banach space (or Hilbert space) $X$, the number $\sup_{x \in X \setminus\{0\}} \frac{\|Sx\|}{\|x\|}$ is not the spectral radius of $S$ but the operator norm. The operator norm is always $\ge$ the spectral radius, but we cannot expect equality in general.

On a Hilbert space, one sufficient condition for equality of the operator norm and the spectral radius is that the operator be self-adjoint or, more generally, normal.

But as pointed out in a comment by Mateusz Kwaśnicki, if $T$ is self-adjoint on $L^2$, this does not imply that $T$ is self-adjoint on $H^1_0$ since the inner product there is different from the inner product on $L^2$.

Here is a concrete **counterexample**:

Let $\Omega = (0,2\pi)$ (endowed with the non-normalised Lebesgue measure) and define $z,v \in H^1_0 := H^1_0(\Omega)$ by
\begin{align*}
  z(x) & = \frac{|\sin(x)|}{\sqrt{\pi}}, \\
  v(x) & = \sin(\frac{1}{2}x)
\end{align*}
for all $x \in (0,2\pi)$.

We define the operator $T$ on $L^2$ by
$$
  Tf = \langle f, z\rangle_{L^2} \cdot z
$$
for all $f \in L^2$. Then $T$ is a self-adjoint rank-$1$ projection on $L^2$ whose norm and spectral radius are thus equal to $1$. Clearly, the range of $T$ is a subset of $H^1_0$.

The restriction of $T$ to $H^1_0$ is again a non-zero projection and thus still has spectral radius $1$. But the operator norm of $T$ on $H^1_0$ is strictly larger than $1$. Indeed, we have
$$
  \|T\|_{H^1_0 \to H^1_0} \ge \frac{\|Tv\|_{H^1_0}}{\|v\|_{H^1_0}} = \frac{\sqrt{512}}{\sqrt{45}\pi} > 1
$$
(we need to compute a few integrals to obtain the equality in the middle, but the computations are rather straightforward).

This proves that the operator norms of $T$ on $L^2$ and on $H^1_0$ are distinct, although the spectral radius on both spaces is $1$. In particular, $T$ cannot be self-adjoint (and not even normal) on $H^1_0$.

**EDIT: An additional observation.** While, in the example above, equality of the spectral radii on both spaces follows from the fact that $T$ acts as a projection on both spaces, I thought it might be worthwhile to point out that the equality of the spectral radii is actual a general fact:

**Proposition.** (Equality of spectral radii) Let $V,X$ be complex Banach spaces such that $V$ is continuously embedded in $X$. Let $T: X \to X$ be a bounded linear operator such that $TX \subseteq V$. Then the spectral radius of the operator $T: X \to X$ coincides with the spectral radius of the restriction $T|_V: V \to V$.

*Proof.* We use the spectral radius formula
$$
  (*) \qquad r(S) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \|S^n\|^{1/n}
$$
which holds for the spectral radius $r(S)$ of each bounded linear operator $S$ on a complex Banach space.

For each $n \in \mathbb{N}$ the operator $(T|_V)^n = (T^n)|_V: V \to V$ factorizes as
$$
  V \hookrightarrow X \overset{T^{n-1}}{\longrightarrow} X \overset{T}{\longrightarrow} V,
$$
so the spectral radius formula $(*)$ implies that $r(T|_V) \le r(T)$. But conversely, the operator $T^n: X \to X$ factorizes as
$$
  X \overset{T}{\longrightarrow} V \overset{(T|_V)^{n-1}}{\longrightarrow} V \hookrightarrow X,
$$
so the spectral radius formula $(*)$ also implies that $r(T) \le r(T|_V)$. This proves the proposition.

**Remark.** What is quite nice about the proposition above is that it does not rely on eigenvalues, so no compactness assumption on the operator $T$ is needed.